# Capture continuous output for external command

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qt5

I'm creating a GUI in qt/C++ for some app that prints continuously to stdout, I need to capture the output, retrieve some data from each line and call `my_function(string S`) on each line.

I have the following code

```
   QProcess *proc = new QProcess();
   QString program = "/pathtomy.py";
   QStringList args = {"myarg"};


   proc->start(program,args);
   proc->waitForFinished();

   QString result=proc->readAllStandardOutput();
   std::string utf8_text = result.toUtf8().constData();
   std::cout << utf8_text ;

// this will continuously print  everything it gets from the command, but I want to retrieve each line and call a function that does some stuff based on the line.
// here I want to capture each line and call my_function(line);
```

The external app could be simulated with something like:

```
i=0
While True:
     i = i+1
    Print("some part of my string , some important string that I want " + i)
```

How to achieve this and capture each line separately? Also should I use multi-threading for such task to run the external app on a separate thread to get a decent performance?

Comment: QStringList lines = result.split('\n');

Comment: but the output will be continuously growing... thus a static array/ list can"t store this...right?

Comment: You used `proc->waitForFinished();` so it does not grow at all. It waits till whatever  program you have has finished execution. Then you grab the all of the text output from the entire execution of your program.

Comment: You probably want to change your implementation to more like this code: [https://gist.github.com/ynonp/8148340](https://gist.github.com/ynonp/8148340)

Comment: well, then it's a mistake I made... surprisingly my cout keeps printing things incrementally... as if it's printing it in real-time and it never stops even with waitForFinished(). Thanks for your link, my external app is supposed to be a kernel, it never finishes, so yeah I will try to follow your link and come back in an hour or so...  thx again

Comment: @drescherjm, sounds like your link worked for me. thx a lot!

Comment: I use a similar approach for several medical imaging tasks at work.

Comment: Oh, I see. Are you plotting the data in real-time too?

Comment: No in my case the returned data always text status information generated in processing of the files.  In some cases the information causes additional processing usually with the dicom images, in other cases it is just sent to the user in a log format.